# Prove the following: Product of Roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals, infinite-product

$1^{(1/1)} \cdot 2^{(1/2)} \cdot 3^{(1/3)} \cdot 4^{(1/4)} \cdot 5^{(1/5)} $.... diverges

well I don't really know if it does but my gut tells me it does:

I can take the log of this product

to create:

$\ln(1) + \frac{\ln(2)}{2} + \frac{\ln(3)}{3} + \frac{\ln(4)}{4} \ldots$

which I believe is asymptotic to the integral from $\int_1^{\infty} \ln(x)/x \ dx$ which is equivalent to:

$$\lim_{c \rightarrow \infty}        \   1/2 \ln(c)^2 - 0 $$

= infinity?

Is the asymptotic assumption correct? If not then how to prove the convergence or divergence of this series?

Comment: The assertion about asymptotic is correct. For proof, note that $\frac{1}{k\log k}\gt \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{dx}{x\log x}$, and for inequality the other way, integrate from $k-1$ to $k$.

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning works just fine. An easier way to see the the series diverges is to see that it's larger than the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this, and the simplest is probably this $\sum_n \frac{\ln n}{n} \geq \sum_n \frac{1}{n} = \infty$, as the later is the harmonic series.